# awk - all rows where half of columns are bigger than x

Tags: linux, bash, awk, command-line

As the title suggests I'm trying to find all rows in an large tsv file, where at least 50% of the columns have a value bigger than a value x using awk.

E.g for x=5:

```
9    6    7    2     3
0    1    2    7     6
1    3    8    9    10
```

should return

```
9    6    7    2     3
1    3    8    9    10
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: I did it in R however the file is too large to read into memory completely. So i would like to preprocess it with bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v t=5 '{c=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) c+=($i>t)} c/NF>0.5' file

9    6    7    2     3
1    3    8    9    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
perl -ane '$x = 5; print if @F / 2 <= grep $_ > $x, @F' -- file.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an input .tsv file which looks like this:

```
Num1    Num2    Num3    Num4    Num5
9       6       7       2       3
0       1       2       7       6
1       3       8       9       10
```

This code will do it in a awk script. I've left comments to see
the form of a script so you can adjust accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# reads from stdin. 
# Usage: $ ./bigcols.awk < input1.tsv


# Run at start.
BEGIN {
#       print "Start" 
#       print "TSV setting. Field seperator set to tab."
        FS = "\t"
        # He wants to find lines with avg greater than var x
        x=5
}

# main. Run for each record. This code uses newlines to denote records.
{
        # Find lines which are of this form: (skip header)
        # #+,
        # ie. start with one or more numbers in column 1.
        if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+/) {
                the_avg = ($1 + $2 + $3 + $4 + $5)/5
                if (the_avg > x) {
                    print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
                }
        }
}

# run at end
#END { print "Stop" }
```